# Django admin list : how to specify custom field instead of model __str__ method?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model that has multi attributes rendered in `__str__` method. I only want to display the name attribute in the admin list display. How do I achieve this without overriding `__str__`? In the example below I have tried using `list_display` in the admin model but Django still renders the attributes in `__str__` defined for the model.

**models.py:**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    Product
    """

    id = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    attributes = models.JSONField()
    labels = models.JSONField()
    name = models.TextField()
    relative_url = models.TextField()
    image = models.URLField()
    delivery = models.TextField()
    online = models.BooleanField()
    is_customizable = models.BooleanField()
    is_exclusive = models.BooleanField()
    url = models.TextField()
    max_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    min_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discount_percentage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    recommended_retail_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        product_str = (
            f"id: {self.id}\n"
            f"attributes: {self.attributes}\n"
            f"labels: {self.labels}\n"
            f"name: {self.name}\n"
            f"relative_url: {self.relative_url}\n"
            f"image: {self.image}\n"
            f"delivery: {self.delivery}\n"
            f"online: {self.online}\n"
            f"is_customizable: {self.is_customizable}\n"
            f"is_exclusive: {self.is_exclusive}\n"
            f"url: {self.url}\n"
            f"max_price: {self.max_price}\n"
            f"min_price: {self.min_price}\n"
            f"currency: {self.currency}\n"
            f"discount_percentage: {self.discount_percentage}\n"
            f"recommended_retail_price: {self.recommended_retail_price}\n"
        )

        return product_str

    def get_absolute_url(self) -> str:
        return reverse("web:product-detail", args=[self.id])

    class Meta:
        db_table = "product"
        ordering = ["recommended_retail_price"]
```

**admin.py:**

```py
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name",)
    form = ProductForm
```

**forms.py:**

```py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize your model admin display using below way:

```py
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("get_name",)
    form = ProductForm

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name  # here you can do whatever you want
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it, still uses __str__ from the model. Can't seem to get anything to override what is in __str__

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was using the default admin forms for the models and not explictly registering my admin forms. I updated my admin.py to explictly register my admin models, e.g.:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "name", "recommended_retail_price", "currency")
    list_per_page = 10
    form = ProductForm
```